# Spark join 2 dataframe based on multiple columns

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I have 2 dataframes df1 and df2. I have join condition for these dataframes defined in a map. However the join column names are different.

I know that I can do like this,
`val df3 = df2.join(df1, df2("col1") <=> df1("col5")`
       `&& df2("col2") <=> df1("col6")`
        `&& df2("col3") <=> df1("col7")`
        `&& df2("col4") <=> df1("col8"),`
    `"left"`
`)`

IS there a way to dynamically create the join condition using values in map.

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```scala
val df3 = df2.join(df1, Seq("col5", "col6", "col7", "col8"), "left")
```

if you previously rename columns from df2 because columns must exist on both sides.